# Python Kafka Comsumer.poll gives error when using gzipped avro format

Tags: apache-zookeeper, kafka-python

I have a line in my code which gives an immediate error when trying to consume messages that are both avro format and gzipped.

```
message = consumer.poll(300000)
```

Here is the consumer config ..

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    bootstrap_servers=broker,
    auto_offset_reset='latest', #new messages from this point
    group_id='xxxxxxxxxx',
    metadata_max_age_ms=300000,
    #value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8'))
    #value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
    value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('latin-1'))
    #value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode())
    )
```

You can see I have tried various decode options which give various errors.

Latin-1

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

ISO-8859-1

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

utf-8

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Any idea how to fix ?
Do I need to add something extra to my consumer config.

Note : The format is dictated by Qlik Replicate software for size and performance reasons and cannot be changed.

Expected the Kafka consumer to be able to consume the messages.